# Post into controller not working correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I've got an entity model with nested class.  FSRHire is the parent and Employee is the child:

```
class FSRHire {
    ...
    public virtual Employee Employee
    ...
}
class Employee {
    ...
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    public DateTime DOB {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

View:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Employee.LastName)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Employee.LastName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Employee.LastName)
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Employee.DOB)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBox(Html.IdFor(model => model.Employee.DOB).ToString(), Model.Employee.DOB.HasValue ? Model.Employee.DOB.Value.ToString("d") : "", new { @class = "date" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Employee.DOB)
</div>
```

The post into the controller doesn't work.  Here is the data from the request:

...Employee.LastName=Worker&Employee_DOB=01%2F01%2F1970& ...

The model binder picks up the name just fine.  The Employee.DOB is null.

It's *probably* caused by the underscore in the DOB field. (Employee_DOB).  I'm wondering why it's like that and how I can fix it.

Comment: It's in System.Web.Mvc.Html in MVC 4.0.  That's proabably it.  I'm looking into where that technique came from.

Comment: I added the tag for it. Anyway, if you didn't change the way the HTML helper produce the markup, I suggest you to open a bug for the MVC team. You should be aware of that ASP.Net-MVC4 is still in beta... :(

Comment: I actually changed the markup to work with the jquery ui datepicker.  (Based on an incorrect blog entry.)  I added the line I had to change in the view to your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be in this format:

```
...Employee.LastName=Worker&Employee.DOB=01%2F01%2F1970& ...
```

Changed from:

```
Employee_DOB=01%2F01%2F1970&
//      ^
```

To

```
Employee.DOB=01%2F01%2F1970&
//      ^
```

Regarding to the View:

```
@Html.TextBox(Html.IdFor(model => model.Employee.DOB).ToString(), Model.Employee.DOB.HasValue ? Model.Employee.DOB.Value.ToString("d") : "", new { @class = "date" })
```

There is no `IdFor` Method in the Web.Mvc dll, you probably wrote it yourself or used some library, anyway it's not working right.

Change the line in the view to look like this:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Employee.DOB, Model.Employee.DOB.HasValue ? Model.Employee.DOB.Value.ToString("d") : "", new { @class = "date" })
```